# Find if a property exists in a class with strtolower

Tags: php, string, class, properties, foreach

How can I check if a property exists in a class and use `strtolower()`? (I can't use `property_exists()` because it won't let me `strtolower()` the properties.) I tried to use `get_object_vars()` and a `foreach()` loop.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Test { 
    public $egg = "yay";
}

$test = new Test();
$find = "EGG";
$vars = get_object_vars($test);

foreach($vars as $var) {
    if(strtolower($var) == strtolower($find))
        echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' found in Test class. Value: ' . $test->{$find};
    else
        echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' not found in Test class.';
}
```

The output:

> Var egg not found in Test class.

What I want it to output:

> Var egg found in Test class. Value: yay

Comment: Use http://php.net/property_exists

Comment: `preg_grep("/$find/i", array_keys($vars))`?

Comment: Because the string could be "EGG" and the property could be "egg". And vice versa.

Comment: `property_exists()` is case sensitive, because all PHP variables are case sensitive in naming. `$test->EGG` and `$test->egg` are two completely different things.

Comment: I know. That's why I want to use strtolower(), so I can get the value of egg (or EGG) even if the user types EGG (or egg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You searched the var instead of the key:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Test { 
    public $egg = "yay";
}

$test = new Test();
$find = "EGG";
$vars = get_object_vars($test);
var_dump($vars);
foreach($vars as $key=>$var) {
    if(strtolower($key) == strtolower($find))
        echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' found in Test class. Value: ' . $test->{strtolower($find)};
    else
        echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' not found in Test class.';
}
```

https://eval.in/107095

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    class Test { 
        public $egg = "yay";
    }
    $test = new Test();
    $find = "EGG";
    $vars = get_object_vars($test);
    foreach($vars as $name => $value) {
        if(strtolower($name) == strtolower($find))
            echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' found in Test class. Value: ' . $test->{strtolower($find)};
        else
            echo 'Var ' . strtolower($find) . ' not found in Test class.';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works if you know that the properties are always lower case, which from your question it seems that you do not (or why search for `EGG` if you already know that it's `egg`).

This will find the correct property whether it is upper, lower or mixed and the `$find` can be upper, lower or mixed:

```
Class Test { 
    public $egg = "yay";
}

$test = new Test();
$find = "EGG";
$vars = implode(',', array_keys(get_object_vars($test)));

if(preg_match("/^$find$/i", $vars, $match)) {
    $prop = $match[0];
    echo 'Var ' . $prop . ' found in Test class. Value: ' . $test->$prop;
} else {
    echo 'Var ' . $prop . ' not found in Test class.';
}
```

Comment: My original solution worked for all cases: https://eval.in/107093 ... questioner called it a "small error" and updated it...*shrug*

Comment: Because it returned an error and it didn't display the value. My edit fixed that...